# Directing an image in 360 degrees to a target

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to move an image from a given x y to a target x y in a single straight line. I am writing a life simulation and need animals to move towards one another.

[Image describing what is mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shVXV.png)

Each animal object holds a target; a javaFX circle whose centre is the desired target, a circle is used to detect collisions easily.

I have been able to achieve movement through solving the angle of the line and setting dx and dy of the image from this angle, however issues arise when the image is travelling at a greater speed than 0.5 (anything slower than 0.5 is fine). When the speed is set greater than 0.5 the animal shakes but does not move in from its position.

```
// called every update
public void target(){
    if (hasTarget()){
        directToTarget();
        checkCollideTarget();
    }
    else{
        getRandomTarget();
    }
}

//returns the angle from the centre of the animal to the centre of the target circle
public double getAngleTo(int tX,int tY){
    double thisX = getImage().getCenterX() + getImage().getTranslateX(),
            thisY = getImage().getCenterY() + getImage().getTranslateY();
    double theta = Math.atan2(tY - thisY, tX - thisX);
    double angle = Math.toDegrees(theta);
    if (angle < 0) {
        angle += 360;
    }
    return angle;
}

// sets dx and dy of the animal determined by the angle
public void directToTarget(){
    double angle = getAngleTo((int)(getTargetCircle().getCenterX() + getTargetCircle().getTranslateX()),
            (int)(getTargetCircle().getCenterY() + getTargetCircle().getTranslateY()));
    setDx((Math.cos(angle) * getSpeed()));
    setDy((Math.sin(angle) * getSpeed()));
}
```

the same targeting functions are also used within the following issues however occur regardless of the speed:

When an animal is targeted to a moving object(another animal) the movement basically replicates the movement of the target animal.

If animals both hold each other as a target they will move towards each other until about 5 pixels away from colliding, at which point they will begin to shake.

I understand this is possibly a big question and would appreciate any time spent trying to help me. I also invite you to try the code, please find it here https://github.com/YJoe/LifeSim/tree/master/src/LS in order to change the speed of the animal please go to the Ant class and change the speed parameter in the super constructor. To target each animal to one another please uncomment two lines that can be found within the Main class. Please note that the only button in the menu that works is pause/play.

Comment: I'm surprised this even works. Your `getAngleTo` method returns degree, but `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` expect radians. Also it shouldn't be necessary to use an angle in the calculation. You should be able to calculate movement like this: position `P`, target position `T`, speed `s` distance moved `D = s * (T-P) / |T-P|`, i.e. by multiplying the speed with the normalized position difference (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Basic_properties). The issue with sufficient large speeds is most likely that the animals can pass through each other in a single update (or degree/radians).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use a different approach altogether. An [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) for the game loop. And vectors for location / velocity / acceleration calculations. It's not hard to learn how to do it. A very good book about how to do this is Daniel Shiffman's [The Nature Of Code](http://natureofcode.com/).

Your special case would be in [Chapter 6, Autonomous Agents](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-6-autonomous-agents/). I did an implementation of 6.4 Arriving Behavior some time ago, so here's just the code for you to look into.

Drag the attractor (the circle), the followers will steer towards it, rotate accordingly while you drag around and slow down and stop once they get close enough to the target location.

Vehicle.java

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.Node;

public class Vehicle extends Sprite {

    public Vehicle(Layer layer, Vector2D location, Vector2D velocity, Vector2D acceleration, double width, double height) {
        super(layer, location, velocity, acceleration, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public Node createView() {
        return Utils.createArrowImageView( (int) width);
    }

}
```

Attractor.java

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class Attractor extends Sprite {

    public Attractor(Layer layer, Vector2D location, Vector2D velocity, Vector2D acceleration, double width, double height) {
        super(layer, location, velocity, acceleration, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public Node createView() {

        double radius = width / 2;

        Circle circle = new Circle( radius);

        circle.setCenterX(radius);
        circle.setCenterY(radius);

        circle.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        circle.setFill(Color.GREEN.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3));

        return circle;
    }

}
```

Sprite.java

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;

public abstract class Sprite extends Region {

    Vector2D location;
    Vector2D velocity;
    Vector2D acceleration;

    double maxForce = Settings.SPRITE_MAX_FORCE;
    double maxSpeed = Settings.SPRITE_MAX_SPEED;

    Node view;

    // view dimensions
    double width;
    double height;
    double centerX;
    double centerY;
    double radius;

    double angle;

    Layer layer = null;

    public Sprite( Layer layer, Vector2D location, Vector2D velocity, Vector2D acceleration, double width, double height) {

        this.layer = layer; 

        this.location = location;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.acceleration = acceleration;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.centerX = width / 2;
        this.centerY = height / 2;

        this.view = createView();

        setPrefSize(width, height);

        // add view to this node
        getChildren().add( view);

        // add this node to layer
        layer.getChildren().add( this);

    }

    public abstract Node createView();

    public void applyForce(Vector2D force) {
        acceleration.add(force);
    }

    public void move() {

        // set velocity depending on acceleration
        velocity.add(acceleration);

        // limit velocity to max speed
        velocity.limit(maxSpeed);

        // change location depending on velocity
        location.add(velocity);

        // angle: towards velocity (ie target)
        angle = velocity.heading2D();

        // clear acceleration
        acceleration.multiply(0);
    }

    /**
     * Move sprite towards target
     */
    public void seek(Vector2D target) {

        Vector2D desired = Vector2D.subtract(target, location);

        // The distance is the magnitude of the vector pointing from location to target.

        double d = desired.magnitude();
        desired.normalize();

        // If we are closer than 100 pixels...
        if (d < Settings.SPRITE_SLOW_DOWN_DISTANCE) {

            // ...set the magnitude according to how close we are.
            double m = Utils.map(d, 0, Settings.SPRITE_SLOW_DOWN_DISTANCE, 0, maxSpeed);
            desired.multiply(m);

        } 
        // Otherwise, proceed at maximum speed.
        else {
            desired.multiply(maxSpeed);
        }

        // The usual steering = desired - velocity
        Vector2D steer = Vector2D.subtract(desired, velocity);
        steer.limit(maxForce);

        applyForce(steer);

    }

    /**
     * Update node position
     */
    public void display() {

        relocate(location.x - centerX, location.y - centerY);

        setRotate(Math.toDegrees( angle));

    }

    public Vector2D getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    public Vector2D getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation( double x, double y) {
        location.x = x;
        location.y = y;
    }

    public void setLocationOffset( double x, double y) {
        location.x += x;
        location.y += y;
    }

}
```

Layer.java

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Layer extends Pane {

    public Layer(double width, double height) {

        setPrefSize(width, height);

    }


}
```

Settings.java

```
package application;


public class Settings {

    public static double SCENE_WIDTH = 1280;
    public static double SCENE_HEIGHT = 720;

    public static int ATTRACTOR_COUNT = 1;
    public static int VEHICLE_COUNT = 10;

    public static double SPRITE_MAX_SPEED = 2;
    public static double SPRITE_MAX_FORCE = 0.1;

    // distance at which the sprite moves slower towards the target 
    public static double SPRITE_SLOW_DOWN_DISTANCE = 100; 

}
```

MouseGestures.java

```
package application;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;


public class MouseGestures {

    final DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();

    public void makeDraggable(final Sprite sprite) {

        sprite.setOnMousePressed(onMousePressedEventHandler);
        sprite.setOnMouseDragged(onMouseDraggedEventHandler);
        sprite.setOnMouseReleased(onMouseReleasedEventHandler);

    }

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            dragContext.x = event.getSceneX();
            dragContext.y = event.getSceneY();

        }
    };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            Sprite sprite = (Sprite) event.getSource();

            double offsetX = event.getSceneX() - dragContext.x;
            double offsetY = event.getSceneY() - dragContext.y;

            sprite.setLocationOffset(offsetX, offsetY);

            dragContext.x = event.getSceneX();
            dragContext.y = event.getSceneY();

        }
    };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

        }
    };

    class DragContext {

        double x;
        double y;

    }

}
```

Main.java

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    static Random random = new Random();

    Layer playfield;

    List<Attractor> allAttractors = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Vehicle> allVehicles = new ArrayList<>();

    AnimationTimer gameLoop;

    Vector2D mouseLocation = new Vector2D( 0, 0);

    Scene scene;

    MouseGestures mouseGestures = new MouseGestures();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // create containers
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        // playfield for our Sprites
        playfield = new Layer( Settings.SCENE_WIDTH, Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT);

        // entire game as layers
        Pane layerPane = new Pane();

        layerPane.getChildren().addAll(playfield);

        root.setCenter(layerPane);

        scene = new Scene(root, Settings.SCENE_WIDTH, Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // add content
        prepareGame();

        // add mouse location listener
        addListeners();

        // run animation loop
        startGame();


    }

    private void prepareGame() {

        // add vehicles
        for( int i = 0; i < Settings.VEHICLE_COUNT; i++) {
            addVehicles();
        }

        // add attractors
        for( int i = 0; i < Settings.ATTRACTOR_COUNT; i++) {
            addAttractors();
        }


    }

    private void startGame() {

        // start game
        gameLoop = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                // currently we have only 1 attractor
                Attractor attractor = allAttractors.get(0);

                // seek attractor location, apply force to get towards it
                allVehicles.forEach(vehicle -> {

                    vehicle.seek( attractor.getLocation());

                });

                // move sprite
                allVehicles.forEach(Sprite::move);

                // update in fx scene
                allVehicles.forEach(Sprite::display);
                allAttractors.forEach(Sprite::display);

            }
        };

        gameLoop.start();

    }

    /**
     * Add single vehicle to list of vehicles and to the playfield
     */
    private void addVehicles() {

        Layer layer = playfield;

        // random location
        double x = random.nextDouble() * layer.getWidth();
        double y = random.nextDouble() * layer.getHeight();

        // dimensions
        double width = 50;
        double height = width / 2.0;

        // create vehicle data
        Vector2D location = new Vector2D( x,y);
        Vector2D velocity = new Vector2D( 0,0);
        Vector2D acceleration = new Vector2D( 0,0);

        // create sprite and add to layer
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle( layer, location, velocity, acceleration, width, height);

        // register vehicle
        allVehicles.add(vehicle);

    }

    private void addAttractors() {

        Layer layer = playfield;

        // center attractor
        double x = layer.getWidth() / 2;
        double y = layer.getHeight() / 2;

        // dimensions
        double width = 100;
        double height = 100;

        // create attractor data
        Vector2D location = new Vector2D( x,y);
        Vector2D velocity = new Vector2D( 0,0);
        Vector2D acceleration = new Vector2D( 0,0);

        // create attractor and add to layer
        Attractor attractor = new Attractor( layer, location, velocity, acceleration, width, height);

        // register sprite
        allAttractors.add(attractor);

    }

    private void addListeners() {

        // capture mouse position
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, e -> {
            mouseLocation.set(e.getX(), e.getY());
        });

        // move attractors via mouse
        for( Attractor attractor: allAttractors) {
            mouseGestures.makeDraggable(attractor);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Utils.java

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineCap;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineJoin;


public class Utils {

    public static double map(double value, double currentRangeStart, double currentRangeStop, double targetRangeStart, double targetRangeStop) {
        return targetRangeStart + (targetRangeStop - targetRangeStart) * ((value - currentRangeStart) / (currentRangeStop - currentRangeStart));
    }

    /**
     * Create an imageview of a right facing arrow.
     * @param size The width. The height is calculated as width / 2.0.
     * @param height
     * @return
     */
    public static ImageView createArrowImageView( double size) {

        return createArrowImageView(size, size / 2.0, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3), 1);

    }

    /**
     * Create an imageview of a right facing arrow.
     * @param width
     * @param height
     * @return
     */
    public static ImageView createArrowImageView( double width, double height, Paint stroke, Paint fill, double strokeWidth) {

        return new ImageView( createArrowImage(width, height, stroke, fill, strokeWidth));

    }   

    /**
     * Create an image of a right facing arrow.
     * @param width
     * @param height
     * @return
     */
    public static Image createArrowImage( double width, double height, Paint stroke, Paint fill, double strokeWidth) {

        WritableImage wi;

        double arrowWidth = width - strokeWidth * 2;
        double arrowHeight = height - strokeWidth * 2;

        Polygon arrow = new Polygon( 0, 0, arrowWidth, arrowHeight / 2, 0, arrowHeight); // left/right lines of the arrow
        arrow.setStrokeLineJoin(StrokeLineJoin.MITER);
        arrow.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.SQUARE);
        arrow.setStroke(stroke);
        arrow.setFill(fill);
        arrow.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

        SnapshotParameters parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
        parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); 

        int imageWidth = (int) width;
        int imageHeight = (int) height;

        wi = new WritableImage( imageWidth, imageHeight);
        arrow.snapshot(parameters, wi);

        return wi;

    }

}
```

Vector2D.java

```
package application;



public class Vector2D { 

    public double x;
    public double y;


    public Vector2D(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void set(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double magnitude() {
        return (double) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    public void add(Vector2D v) {
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
    }

    public void add(double x, double y) {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
    }

    public void multiply(double n) {
        x *= n;
        y *= n;
    }

    public void div(double n) {
        x /= n;
        y /= n;
    }

    public void normalize() {
        double m = magnitude();
        if (m != 0 && m != 1) {
            div(m);
        }
    }

    public void limit(double max) {
        if (magnitude() > max) {
            normalize();
            multiply(max);
        }
    }

    static public Vector2D subtract(Vector2D v1, Vector2D v2) {
        return new Vector2D(v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y);
    }

    public double heading2D() {
        return Math.atan2(y, x);
    }

}
```

And a screenshot:

[image]